# Segmentation fault in C while using int pointer argument

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I know - another segmentation fault question...
I am trying to run my professor's function `enterValue`, but keep receiving a segmentation fault error. Am I the one doing something wrong, or is there a bug that I'm not catching in his code? Note that the declaration `int*     length;` actually was written in his original code as `int     length;`. Given that the final argument `valuePtr` is intended to be a pointer to an int, that's what I thought the argument `length` should be defined as.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LINE        256

char    line[MAX_LINE];

int*     length;

void    enterValue      (const char*    descriptionPtr,
                     int            min,
                     int            max,
                     int*           valuePtr
                    )
{
  do
  {
    printf("Please enter the %s (%d-%d): ",descriptionPtr,min,max);
    fgets(line,MAX_LINE,stdin);
    *valuePtr = strtol(line,NULL,10);
  }
  while  ( (*valuePtr < min) || (*valuePtr > max) );

}

int main ()
{
  enterValue ("number of numbers", 1, 256, length); 
  return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

When I run this, I get the following:

```
Please enter the number of numbers (1-256): 4
Segmentation fault
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, you should have left the original declaration of `int length`.  Pass a pointer to it in the call with

```
enterValue ("number of numbers", 1, 256, &length);
```

That makes the argument a pointer to an int, and allows the function to write into the variable.

My making length a pointer—and especially not initializing where it points—you have created a "write to random memory" algorithm.

Comment: Oh my god, I'm such an idiot. Sorry for wasting everyone's time :-)

Comment: @user1185790:  No sweat.  Making mistakes is how we learn.  Imagine how little you would learn if everything "just worked" the first time!

Answer (score 3):

The integer pointer is not pointing to anything when you call entervalue function.
you have to have `length = &some_integer;` so that integer pointer `length` points to some integer.

Answer (score 2):

Two mistakes I see, first `length` should not be not a pointer

```
int length;
```

Second, pass the address of `length`, as you want the function to modify `length`

```
enterValue ("number of numbers", 1, 256, &length);
```